# Uploading image to Twitter via Node.js results in HTTP error 400 (bad request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to upload an image to Twitter by sending it in a certain Discord channel. This is the code I'm using:

```js
var number = 0;

function downloadJPG(url) { //This function downloads the image in jpg format
    request.get(url).on('error', console.error).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg'));
}

if (message.attachments.every(attachIsImageJPG)) {
      downloadJPG(message.attachments.first().url);
      var imageToPostJPG = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg');
      client.post('media/upload', {media: imageToPostJPG}, function(err, data, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    number = number+1
    client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Success Cop #'+number, media_ids: data.media_id_string}, function(err, params, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(params);
        });
    });
}
```

The image should be uploaded to Twitter with the status, but only the status gets uploaded, and this is what I see in the console:

> ```js
> Error: HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request
>     at Request._callback (C:\Users\Silvano\Desktop\Twitter\node_modules\twitter\lib\twitter.js:221:9)
>     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Silvano\Desktop\Twitter\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:200:13)
>     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Silvano\Desktop\Twitter\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:200:13)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Silvano\Desktop\Twitter\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
>     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:205:15)
>     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
> {
>   request: '/1.1/media/upload.json',
>   error: 'media type unrecognized.'
> }
> ```

How can I resolve this error and get the image uploaded too?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the stream must be finished before `readFileSync` reads it.

```
// modified to indicate completion by calling callback
function downloadJPG(url, callback) { //This function downloads the image in jpg format
  let stream = request.get(url).on('error', console.error).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg'));
  stream.on('finish', callback);
}

// modified to do the twtr work in the callback
if (message.attachments.every(attachIsImageJPG)) {
    downloadJPG(message.attachments.first().url, function() {
        var imageToPostJPG = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg');
        client.post('media/upload', {media: imageToPostJPG}, function(err, data, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
        number = number+1
        client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Success Cop #'+number, media_ids: data.media_id_string}, function(err, params, res) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log(params);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Side note: I find that after one or two steps, the callback style is too hard to write and read, and that promises are preferable.